# How to write -exec command with different format

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script

Someone gave this script for log rotation. I want to know what is logic behind it. 
Though I understand all except --exec which was little confusing for me.

## original Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
NOW=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
echo $
cd /home/cloud360mssadmin/
find Tahoe-Broadcast.log.*  -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "/home/cloud360mssread/$0-`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`"' {} \;
```

I think 'echo $' missing variable.

The same script I implemented in the different way ( for testing purpose only)  which was successfully executed.

```
#!/bin/bash
# this is scrpt for the log rotation
set -x
cd /var/log
echo " we are enter the `pwd`"
NOW="$(date +'%d-%m-%y')"
echo $NOW
find vmware* -exec mv '{}'  /home/vinod/ \;
cd /home/vinod/
find vmware* -exec tar -rvf vmware.tar {} \;
```

My task is to rotate the log and compress it.

Comment: Where is the `--exec` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your exact question is. What specifically do you need help with, or what is the problem?

Comment: There are plenty of utilities to rotate logs on Linux (including the aptly named `logrotate`), so why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
sh -c 'echo 0:$0, 1:$1, 2:$2' one two three
```

this yields:

```
0:one, 1:two, 2:three
```

In other words, `sh -c` launches a temporary script (`echo 0:$0, 1:$1, 2:$2`) that receives the rest of the arguments of `sh` as its own args. Normally the first of these args is assumed to be a command name (but this is a convention).

So in your script:

```
-exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "/home/cloud360mssread/$0-`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`"' {} \;
```

is executing:

```
mv {the_file} /home/cloud360mssread/{the_file}-{timestamp}
```

which is a bit contrived since:

```
-exec mv "{}" "/home/cloud360mssread/{}-$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")" \;
```

would have worked just as well.

Comment: It clears my doubt xenoid. though when I am executing the script it is giving me an error regarding 'mv ' command.  I tried the different option of mv command. 
****
++ find backupmysqld.tar backuptar.tar yumlog.tar yumlogtest.tar -exec mv '{}' '/home/vinod/{}-06-08-18' '{}' ';'
mv: target `backupmysqld.tar' is not a directory
mv: target `backuptar.tar' is not a directory
mv: target `yumlog.tar' is not a directory
mv: target `yumlogtest.tar' is not a directory
****

Comment: Sorry, copied/pasted the wrong thing. Command fixed.